# .Net MVC certification way

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, certificate

At beginning next year I'll end my education and start professional way with web app development (my target is Web development especially asp.net mvc). At this moment I work and each day I still progress my skills. I think it's difficult question but I want to hear from more experienced persons that it is really sense with achive certificates (if yes what certificates are important and for which I should focus) or rather focus on self build-up carrier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking certifications won't do you any harm, as going through the process of studying for them should improve your knowledge and help develop your skills. The official study guides for some of the [MCSD certifications](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-gb/mcsd-certification.aspx) cover a lot of material and show you how to build some cool demo apps, so I'd recommend targeting them if any.

In interviews though, most employers are more interested in how good you are at describing technical concepts and what your previous projects were than what certificates you've got. So just don't expect having a few certificates to be a substitute for being able to demonstrate strong technical skills and experience.

Answer (score 0):

Only certification are not useful. better you get advance knowledge and experience in appropriate technology. As of now you are fresher so first start preparing self study and small smalpoc with each subject.

if you are want to do certification only for getting good job and salary then it will not be useful. because once you mention certification in your resume then expectation of interview panel from you will be little bit high.

So think all way and take proper decision. All the best.